# Is there a mistake in this logical problem?

Tags: logic, puzzle

I've found an oldish book with logical puzzles.

In one of the puzzles I was not able to find a single correct answer - IMO at least two solutions fit - either I miss something or there is a mistake.

The puzzle goes like this:

- there are tree paths - you need to choose one - **only one should be right**;
- each path has a sign - **at least one sign is false**.

Now, here are the signs:

- A: The correct path is either B or C.
- B: If (and only if) this is the wrong path, then the correct path is C.
- C: The correct path is either this one or B.

Essentially A and C say the same, so they are either both true or both false.

It is easy to see that path A may be the answer (then all 3 signs are wrong) and path C is wrong (this would make all 3 signs right).

My confusion comes from trying path B:

- if path B is the right path:

  - sign A is true;
  - sign C is true;
  - then sign B must be false:

    - *as far as I understand the implication on sign B allows this situation - while the answer in the book says that this sign is right as well, hence all three signs are true, hence B cannot be the answer.*

Am I right saying that it's not possible to deterministically say that A is a correct path (i.e. it may be A or B)?

Comment: When sign B says "... the correct one is C", does it mean that C is the correct path? Or is it perhaps saying that what its says on C's sign is true?

Comment: @TheoBendit, it says about the path - corrected to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If path B is correct sign B must indeed be false and the sign says

"B is wrong" $\iff$ "C is correct".

But in this situation the truth value of "C is correct" is *false* and "B is wrong" also has value "false" (as we're in the situation where B is actually correct, remember), so the **equivalence** is true. So sign B would be true, your book is correct, and we again have a contradiction.

Comment: If you interpret the statement on $B$ as a counterfactual (ie "in every possible world where  $B$ is wrong $C$ is right, and vice-versa"), then it is false. Because there still exists the logically valid possibility of both $B$  and  $C$ being wrong, regardless what their present actual status is. But that's a pretty non-standard interpretation for the implication.

Comment: Ah, damn. it's the **and only if** part that my brain was skipping. I was thinking about `!B ⟹ C` - hence the confusion.

Comment: @Werolik you see that the exact formulation is indeed essential.

Answer (score 0):

Sign B is saying that either both halves are true, or both halves are false.
If B is the correct path, then both halves are false, so sign B is true.

Answer (score 0):

If path B is correct, then both these statements are [vacuously true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3328481/21813):
$$\text{B is the wrong path } \implies \text{the correct path is C}\\
 \text{the correct path is C } \implies \text{B is the wrong path}.$$
In other words: if path B is correct, then sign B *is* correct.